# MySQL Workbench wrong configuration file path

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.2.4. Whenever I install it or extract its winrar file it sets automatically a configuration path file in a Connection. But in my case it sets it automatically but it set the path of a file which never been created. I installed MySQL Workbench 6.2.4 but showing me a path `"ProgramFiles\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini"` which did not exist but I tried to create a `my.ini` file through "option file" option that it gives me that path not found and also in my mysql directory that is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL` 6.2 workbench does not contain `my.ini` or `my.conf` file. Also whenever I tried to Connect it gives me an error which is:

> "Could not connect, server may not be running. (16001)"

I know this question is been asked for many times but still I could not found a solution for my problem. I also want to say that I could not find mysql server option in `services.msc` through which I could start my server.

[image: connection error]
[image: could not save configuration file]
[image: manage server connections]

I hope these Screenshots are helpful.

Comment: Did you install mysql first? if so, did you open up a cmd.exe window (open in admin mode), find your mysql installation and try starting the mysql server manually http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html are there errors?

Comment: Do you mean MySql CommunityServer?

Comment: Yes? It's strange that the service is not in your services.msc, so it seems to me that either it was not installed, or not installed to run when you start your computer.

Comment: Please make sure you installed MySQL Server first, and confirm that you started it and can access it. I suggest you use the [MySQL Installer for Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) application to manage (install/configure) your MySQL products, and suggest you also use it to install [MySQL Notifier](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/notifier/) to start/stop MySQL server.

Comment: @AsadJivani I would start the whole process in a more clean manner. I would start by downloading mysql and installing it in `C:\<folder>` and then set the Environment Variables for mysql. After that I would suggest testing that mysql is working by running `cmd` (Start > type cmd > HIT Enter). In cmd Prompt if you type mysql, it should switch to `mysql>` in your command prompt. After that you can now do your workbench config pointing to your mysql folder in C:\<folder> Where `<folder>` is a new folder you create and name and install mysql in. Hope this helps... if not just shout :-).

Comment: Please accept answer Daniel's answer below (if you think it is the right answer)! His solution (plus restarting server and MySQL workbench) worked for me.

Comment: This error is present in MySQL version 8.0 as well. The MySQL Workbench 8.0 is trying to access my previous installation .ini file, the sys.config.path has not been properly updated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Edit `%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\server_instances.xml` and replace

`<value type="string" key="sys.config.path">%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini</value>`

with

`<value type="string" key="sys.config.path">%ProgramData%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini</value>`

Comment: Thanks for the info -- looks like an error on the MySQL-side (they just didn't update that default string). However, once changed I had to restart my server and MySQL workbench to get the changes to show up in workbench (there is a "refresh" button under the server information, but pressing it made no changes until restarting workbench).

Comment: This didn't work for me. The workbench now says that it's reading from the correct location, but it's not using the values that I set in my.ini. There are read when I use mysql from the command prompt. I restarted the MySQL service.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to MySQL Server 8.0 from several prior versions resulted in old values remaining unchanged in the following parameters in `%AppData%\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\server_instances.xml` (the file Daniel mentioned in his '15 post):

`<value type="string" key="sys.mysqld.service_name">MySQL57</value>`

`<value type="string" key="name">Local MySQL57</value>`

`<value type="string" key="sys.config.path">%ProgramData%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini</value>`

A more difficult to find parameter also remained unchanged.
Several lines below the line beginning with this text: 
<value type="object" struct-name="db.mgmt.ServerInstance",
this parameter was left unchanged:
`<value type="string" key="name">Pearl</value>`

Changing these values corrected the display in the "Server Status/Administration - Server Status" panel where the filename displayed after "Configuration File" had been incorrect.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, in my file %AppData%\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\server_instances.xml I haven't those lines and I have added manually it, just under basedir and data dir value type. Is that correct or I am missing something? I'm using MySQL 8.0